# While passing an array through a function in C++/C, why address of array is used in actual parameter whereas the array in formal parameter?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, function, function-call

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int func(int ar[5]){
    //the code is written here with returning whatever the requirement is
}
int main(){
    int ar[5];
    func(ar);
    return 0;
}
```

In this kind of situation where we are passing array through a function why the address of the array is used in actual parameter whereas the array in formal parameter?

Comment: For C [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3), there is a similar section for C++ [C++17 Standard - 7.2 Array-to-pointer conversion](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4741.pdf#section.7.2)

Comment: How about `func()` taking two args; `int *ar` and `size_t len`? That way `func()` could be called not just with `ar[]` but any array of ints, with arbitrary length.

Answer (score 2):

This is because C handled arrays weirdly.

In C, arrays convert to a pointer to their first element at the drop of a hat, cannot be passed as arguments to a function, cannot be returned from functions, and cannot be copied by assignment.

C++, originally based off C, carries these screwed up design decisions as a legacy issue.  Fixing them would break insane amounts of code.

If you want an array that behaves more reasonable, use `std::array`.

```
void foo(int[5]);
```

this is actually taking an `int*` argument.

```
int arr[7];
foo(arr);
```

this converts the 7 element `arr` to a pointer and passes it to `foo`.  Which seems to take `int[5]` but that `5` does **nothing**.

Yes this is utterly crazy.

Now,

```
void bar(int(&)[5])
```

because C does not have references, the above is an actual reference to an array if 5 elements, so

```
bar(arr)
```

won't compile.

Comment: Compilers should have a switch to require a '&' when passing an array and, if missing, generate an 'array copy' warning or 'array length unknown' error, as appropriate.

Comment: Nobody benefits from your johnny-come-lately opinion about a design decision made half a century ago. One could argue no other option was feasible since the necessary semantics and supporting software had not been developed. You could not even write `a = b` for structures at that time, let alone pass aggregates of any kind to functions. Ranting about it is unhelpful. One can easily suggest modern designs would be done differently without disparaging pioneers.

Comment: @eric Calling a mistake a mistake, even in a 50 year old design, even if I could not have done better at the time, has value.  Saying they made mistakes is not "disparaging" them.  They wrote an amazing language and changed the world with it; they did not do so perfectly.

Comment: “Screwed up” and “utterly crazy” are not neutral expressions. Even saying it is a mistake is a value judgment that the decision was erroneous given the knowledge available at the time it was made. Making a decision that is reasonable based on the knowledge and resources available at the time it is made is not a mistake even if it has undesired consequences that could have, in retrospect, been avoided.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing weird, nor screwed up about how arrays are passed in C.  C is expressed pretty simply, really.  C /does/ have references; they are explicit, so, easy to see when they're in use.  We call them pointers.

One simply needs to understand that there is not dedicated storage for array types, that arrays are not first-class types, so, won't behave like first-class types.  Can't be assigned into (directly), nor passed into and out of functions directly.

In C/C++ we use pointers to refer to a chunk of memory where the contents of the array are stored.

So, all that's left is that we understand that when we declare an array, the name of the array is really a pointer to the beginning of the array.

```
int a[12] ;
/* a's type is this: */
int *a ;
```

So, when we "pass an array" to a function, we are copying the *pointer* into the function.  The semantics are straightforward, and entirely consistent (unlike Java).

The array, itself, is never passed directly.

Finally, realise that there is no difference between a pointer to a single integer, and a pointer to a contiguous chunk of integers in memory.

Remember, `a[i]` is equivalent to `*(a+i)`.  So, in this example:

```
int i = 12 ;
int *p = &i ;
```

, `*p` is the same as `*(p+0)`; the `p` can be thought of as an array of length 1.

With a slight change in perspective you should be able to see the simplicity, the elegance, that is C.

Comment: what's your definition of "first-class types"? That isn't a term used by the Standard.  Arrays do have storage just the same as any other variable, and defining an array defines a block of storage (it does not define a pointer). The type of `a` is `int[12]` , not `int *`.  If you doubt this then read the standard, and/or test it with  `sizeof` .

Comment: They are not first-class, because they can not be assigned into, nor passed into nor returned from functions.

If int[12] where a type, then we could use that as the type of a formal parameter.  You *can* declare a parameter so, but, the 12 is meaningless, and if you check the size of this parameter, it is pointer-sized.

Saying int a[12] causes static or stack storage to be put aside, yes, but, quite thinly, a is, indeed, a pointer.  *(a+5) works just fine.

The semantics, when "passing an array" into a function, are exactly the semantics of passing a pointer in.

Comment: Sorry but you are incorrect.  `int[12]` is a type,  try printing `sizeof(int[12])`. You can also have a pointer to `int[12]` .    It is true that  declarations in function parameters can have different meaning to declarations outside of function parameters, however `int a[12];` is not a function parameter. Your mistake is assuming that the behaviour of function parameters is the same as for all declarations .

Comment: I am neither confused, nor incorrect.  Nor did I make a mistake.

I'm sorry I can't help you understand what a first-class data type is.

Did you use int[12] as the type of a formal parameter?  Did you check its size?

Arrays are not first-class types in C.  They can not be directly passed into, nor from, functions.

Yes, declaring arrays is a wee bit magic, but, the semantics of passing variables in C is quite straight-forward.  That includes arrays.

The Standard doesn't say that they're not elephants, either, but, ya know what?  They're not elephants, either.

Comment: "first-class type" isn't standard terminology,  It's a moot point to talk about whether or not arrays are such a thing; instead we can just talk about the properties of arrays directly.  I'm not disputing that arrays can't be passed directly to or from functions ,  the problem is your false claim that arrays don't have dedicated storage , and your false claim that `int a[12];` (NOT in the context of a function parameter) means that the type of `a` is `int *`.